# Join three tables using single query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, left-join

I have three tables and I want to join them.

Joining two tables works perfectly, but joining three tables returns one row only

Table names

- userDetails
- saletrack
- paymentDetails

Query #1:

```
SELECT  
    `userdetails`.CustomerIndex, 
    `userdetails`.FristName,
    SUM(`paymentdetails`.Amountofpaying) TotalPaid
FROM
    `userdetails`
LEFT JOIN 
    `paymentdetails` ON `userdetails`.CustomerIndex=`paymentdetails` .CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    `userdetails`.CustomerIndex,`userdetails`.FristName
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT  
    `userdetails`.CustomerIndex, 
    `userdetails`.FristName,
    SUM(`saletrack`.Total) Totalbilled
FROM 
    `userdetails`
LEFT JOIN 
    `saletrack` ON `userdetails`.CustomerIndex = `saletrack`.CustomerId
GROUP BY 
    `userdetails`.CustomerIndex, `userdetails`.FristName
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT 
    s.CustomerId, 
    SUM(s.Total) Totalbilled, 
    p.CustomerID, 
    SUM(p.Amountofpaying) TotalPaid
FROM  
    `userdetails` AS ud
LEFT JOIN 
    `saletrack` AS s ON ud.CustomerIndex = s.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN 
    `paymentdetails` AS p ON ud.CustomerIndex = p.CustomerID
WHERE 
    p.CustomerID = ud.CustomerIndex
    AND s.CustomerId = ud.CustomerIndex
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Show some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Either this is `mysql`, or this is (Microsoft) `sql-server` - but it cannot possibly be both at the same time..... please remove the extra database tag to make things clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned  **ud.CustomerIndex = s.CustomerId && ud.CustomerIndex = p.CustomerID** in joins then no need to put in where condition again. Try this:

```
SELECT s.CustomerId, SUM( s.Total ) Totalbilled, p.CustomerID, SUM( p.Amountofpaying ) TotalPaid
FROM  `userdetails` AS ud
LEFT JOIN  `saletrack` AS s ON ud.CustomerIndex = s.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN  `paymentdetails` AS p ON ud.CustomerIndex = p.CustomerID
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: dude it also return one row only

Comment: check this image for see data and what i expecting  
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fOlB4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

we need to add grouped by query

```
SELECT s.CustomerId, SUM( s.Total ) Totalbilled, p.CustomerID, SUM( p.Amountofpaying ) TotalPaid
FROM  `userdetails` AS ud
LEFT JOIN  `saletrack` AS s ON ud.CustomerIndex = s.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN  `paymentdetails` AS p ON ud.CustomerIndex = p.CustomerID
WHERE p.CustomerID = ud.CustomerIndex
AND s.CustomerId = ud.CustomerIndex
***GROUP BY ud.CustomerIndex, ud.FristName***
LIMIT 0 , 30
```